# Android refresh button

Tags: android

Hai, 
I am developing an application in Android.
In that there is a refresh button.
If I click that button, the page needs to be reloaded like when execution begins.
Is there any built in method in Android for getting this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd need to reload the whole thing? Why not just load the specific sections that have changed? For instance, if you have a ListView, you can just notify it of a change and refresh it specifically.

Comment: Here I want to develop a puzzle. So when the user clicks the refresh button, it needs refresh. That is the reason. So can u please add some more suggestions

Answer (score 1):

In your current activity, launch your activity again, and call finish()

Answer (score 0):

This is a refresh button method, but it works well in my application.

```
public void refresh(View view){          //refresh is onClick name given to the button
    onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Intent i = new Intent(lala.this, lala.class);  //your class
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```